# How can I configure access from external ip to internal ip on GCP through nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, gerrit

Can't connect to application through External IP.

I started gerrit code review application on GCP's vm instance(CentOS 7). 
It works on http://localhost:8080 and I can't connect to it through external IP. Also I tried to create NGINX reverse proxy, but probably my configuration is wrong. By the way after installing NGINX, the starter page were shown on external ip.

```
# nginx configuration /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;

auth_basic "Welcomme to Gerrit Code Review Site!";

location / {
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
}

gerrit.config
[httpd]
    listenUrl = proxy-http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

Comment: The address `localhost` aka `127.0.0.1` is not addressable outside the OS. These are internal loopback addresses. Does your instance have a public IP address or have you configured your instance with only private IP addresses? Improve your question with details. A reverses proxy to get out to the Internet is called a NAT or PAT. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, it has configured external ip.

Answer (score 0):

You use localhost as a server_name. I think that may cause conflict, because you connect to your server externally. You don't need server_name, cause you are going connect to your server by ip. And I recommend you enable logs in your nginx config. It will help you with bug fixing.

I recommend you try this config:

```
server {
listen 80;

access_log /var/log/nginx/gerrit_access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/gerrit_error.log;

location / {
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't help.

Comment: @Alex did you get some error or empty page? What say nginx logs?

Answer (score 0):

1. add a line in /etc/hosts
   127.0.0.1 internal.domain
2. Update proxy config
   proxy_pass   http://internal.domain:8080;

It works with me